# Different labels for input file types in PHP/HTML

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I've a really simple problem I can't seem to fix :( .

I have the following PHP variable:

```
$nrofattachments="2";
```

And in my HTML code I've something like this to show the number of file upload fields:

```
<?For($i=1;$i <= $nrofattachments; $i++) {?>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="attachments" class="control-label">Attachment(s)</label>
      <input name="attachment[]" type="file" id="attachments" size="30"/>
   </div>
<?}?>
```

What I want to achieve is different labels for each input file type...

Comment: What sort of different labels? Totally different?

Comment: Yep totally different ones. I already came up with a solution similar to Hanky Panky's with +1 / +2, but I want something like: "Resume", "Motivation letter".

Answer (score 1):

```
<? 
 for($i=1;$i <=$nrofattachments; $i++) 
 {
      echo '<div class="form-group">
      <label for="attachments['.$i.']" class="control-label">Attachment '.$i.'</label>
      <input name="attachment['.$i.']" type="file" id="attachments['.$i.']" size="30"/>
      </div>';
  }
?>
```